# publish asp.net website in subfolder

Tags: asp.net

I need to publish my website into a subfolder of an existing one. Notice that there's no way to create a subdomain (e.g.: http://mynewwebsite.example.com), no way to access to IIS.
At the moment I just tried to use the Publish command from my VS2010 and copy/paste file from my disk to subfolder domain via FTP.
This is the error I get:

```
The file '/SUBFOLDERNAME/default.aspx' has not 
been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested.
```

Is there someone who can help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a fair enough question about publishing an app using a **development** tool. It's valid on both serverfault and SO because it stradles both site topics.

Answer (score 1):

I would classify it as a serverfault question. But since you asked my two cents.

You could set this in your web.config

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
        ...
    </system.web>   
</location>
```

What it does?

> **inheritInChildApplications**
>
> Optional Boolean attribute.
>
> Specifies whether configuration settings that are specific to a
>   certain location (such as the root directory of a Web site) are
>   inherited by applications that exist in subdirectories.
>
> The default is True.

More Info: [How to disable web.config Inheritance for Child Applications in Subfolders in ASP.NET?](http://aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/how-to-disable-web-config-inheritance-for-child-applications-in-subfolders-in-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: Hi naveen, thanks a lot for your reply. So I've to change the web.config contained into subfolder, is it right?

Comment: no you have to specify that in your root we.config. please read the article caarefully

Answer (score 1):

> no way to access to IIS

You *must* create an application (virtual directory) in IIS the first time you publish your application.  If you can't access IIS directly, you can alter your web.config as suggested in another answer.  **But that only works with IIS 7.5 (Server 2008 R2)** and later.  If you're not running at least Server 2008 R2, you won't be able to do this without accessing IIS.